# Font resizing itself on browser resize in Fraction Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, font-size

I am using Fraction Slider on my site and I am facing a strange issue. Whenever the browser window is resized to smaller widths and then brought to the original full-width the font size for the paragraphs used in the slider increase on its own, instead of resuming the original size.
Can anyone help me with the same?

Here's a link to my page: http://www.electronicaems.com/index.html

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 errors on your page that may or may not be causing some problems:

```
Uncaught TypeError: window.attachEvent is not a function
http://www.electronicaems.com/js/respond.min.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
langscript.js:30 Uncaught TypeError: langmenu.find is not a function
index.html:575 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined
```

Comment: I have checked these issues, but the issue still persists. I think the problem is the jquery.fractionslider.js in the function resizeSlider(). How do I manage that?